# Can't query newly created field after deploying change set (works in sandbox)

Tags: apex, soql, query, developer-console, query-editor

I created a field 'Legal_Records_Parent_Box_Folder_Id__c' in a sandbox for the Account object, deployed the field to production, with a few scripts where the field was referenced.

[image]

When I query the field in the Production org, the query editor can't find it.

[image]

Yet when I query it in the sandbox, it works fine without any problems.
[image]

I'm honestly at a lost for why this is not appearing in the production org. I can find the field when I search it and I can't even delete it because the org knows I use the field in multiple scripts. Does anyone know why this is happening or how I can fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you deployed the field but didn't deploy any profiles then the field security needs to be updated. By default when you deploy a field on its own nobody has access to view it or edit it. Check your field level security for your new field in production.

Comment: Totally forgot to redeploy a profile. You were completely right, it was not visible for anyone. Making it visible to system administrator fixes it. Thank you so much.